# CreateObject doesn't work in Class Module (Visual Basic 6)

Tags: class, oop, vb6, outlook, createobject

in a VB6 project, this code worked for sending an email via Outlook 2013 using the Microsoft Office Outlook 15.0 Object Library:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
Set mail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
mail.To = txt_Recipient
mail.Subject = txt_Subject
mail.body = txt_Inhalt.Text
mail.Send
```

Now when I tried to transfer the same code into a class module, it kept throwing an error 429 that it couldn't create the object in the third line. Any idea why it doesn't work in a class module while it does when being directly coded in the Command_Click event?

Code in the class:

```
Public objOutlook As outlook.Application
Public Sub MailSenden(ByVal empfaenger As String, ByVal betreff As String, ByVal inhalt As String)
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim mail As outlook.MailItem
Set mail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

mail.To = empfaenger
mail.Subject = betreff
mail.body = inhalt
mail.Send

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help you can give me!
Colin

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you're using late binding when you have the Outlook 15.0 type library handy (and referenced in your project). Have you tried:

```
Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
```